# How to match a regex with words followed by date?

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to write a regex to match sentences like these:

```
"I rated Minions (2015)..."
"I rated Beauty and the Beast (2015)..."
```

I've tried a regex like:

```
I rated \\w+ \\(\\b(18|19|20)\\d{2}\\b\\)
```

but it works only in the first case, when the title is a single word.

Between "I rated" and the year there is a title of a movie with no fixed length. Could you help me?

Comment: Try replacing `\\w+` with `[^.?!(]*`, and remove both `\\b`s

Comment: If you only want to match word character with spaces in between `I rated \\w+ (?:\\w+ )*\\((?:1[89]|20)\\d{2}\\)` https://regex101.com/r/5YXITG/1

Comment: If your sentences are single-line "I rated..." you can just non-capture "I rated" with a lookbehind and parse everything else until end of sentence. Otherwise maybe use the last parenthesis as delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Try using regex like

```
\[^.?!(]* \\((18|19|20)\\d{2}\\)\
```

OR

```
\\w+ (?:\\w+ )*\\((?:1[89]|20)\\d{2}\\)
```

Comment: I think in the first pattern, the `\[` should be `[` and you can omit the ending backslash

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work... It says ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '^'```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- you don't *really* need to validate the year
- your text has mixed spurious sentences, as opposed to one-liner "I rated..."
- you want to do something with the movie title and year separately

You can use:

```
String text = "I rated Minions (2015)... I like turtles. "
    + "I rated Beauty and the Beast (2015)... "
    + "I rated rare live footage of Louis XVI being beheaded (1789)";

//                                 | starts with "I rated"
//                                 |       | group 1 with the title
//                                 |       |     | open parenthesis
//                                 |       |     |  | group 2 with non-validated year
//                                 |       |     |  |     | closing parenthesis
//                                 |       |     |  |     | 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("I rated (.+?) \\((\\d+)\\)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.printf(
      "Title: %s - Year: %s%n", 
      // title is back-referenced as group 1
      matcher.group(1), 
      // year is back-referenced as group 2
      matcher.group(2)
  );
}
```

... which will return:

```
Title: Minions - Year: 2015
Title: Beauty and the Beast - Year: 2015
Title: rare live footage of Louis XVI being beheaded - Year: 1789
```